# Is it possible for me to set background colors for tds in the same column?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

I am currently working on a project which i would like to be allowed to highlight tds for 1 column at a time. In the event that there are no highlights in any other columns, any column is allowed. Thanks in advance. Mentioned below are my codes.

```
<style>
    .highlight { background:yellow; }
</style>

<script>

$(function() {
    $('td').click(function() {
        alert(event.target.id);
       $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});
</script>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%
ArrayList<String> rooms = new ArrayList<String>();
rooms.add("GSR_2-1");
rooms.add("GSR_2-2");
rooms.add("GSR_2-3");
rooms.add("GSR_2-4");
ArrayList<String> time = new ArrayList<String>();
time.add("0800");
time.add("0830");
time.add("0900");
time.add("0930");
%>
<table width="100%" border="1">
<%
    for(int x = 0 ; x<time.size() ; x++){
        out.println("<tr>");
        for(int y = 0 ; y<rooms.size() ; y++){
            out.println("<td id="+rooms.get(y) +">");
            out.println(rooms.get(y)+" "+time.get(x));
            out.println("</td>");
        }
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
%>
```

Comment: The answer to your question is Yes, it's possible. What have you tried? What do you have a problem with?

Comment: i was thinking of using a static variable to store the room and match it but it did not work. Besides that i was also thinking of using a hidden field to store this value. Is this viable? Appreciate your response

Comment: A static Java variable? For a JavaScript thing? And why would you need a hidden field? You don't have any form. Why not just a JavaScript variable?

Comment: once you initialize a variable, would it be stored even after the function ends? i was worried that the variable would not be stored

Comment: If it's not a local variable, yes. But as the answer of @xdazz shows, you don't even need any variable.

Comment: so .find is able to help me check if any of the rows is "highlighted". Is that what you mean by me not needing any stored variable?

Answer (score 2):

Is this you want?

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var $td = $(this);
    $td.closest('table').find('tr').each(function() {
        $(this).find('td:eq('+$td.index()+')').toggleClass("highlight");
    });
});
```

[***The working demo.***](http://jsfiddle.net/eHHDd/)

Comment: Sorry xdazz, this is not what i am looking for. What i need is to be able to click on individual td in a column. Once i click on this td, other tds in other columns would not be able to be clicked. Only tds in the same column are able to be clicked. Thanks anyway

Comment: @KennethLiow The idea is the same, use the index to select the td in the same column.

Comment: @xdazz: I think OP only wants to be able to highlight 1 column at a time at most. If a column is highlighted no other column can be highlighted at the same time. If a column is currently highlighted, clicking any of the other columns should not do anything until the current highlighted column is clicked again to remove the highlight.

Comment: How should i change it such that is able to do that? Would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use a class for every column and do this:

HTML

```
<html>

    <head>

        <title>Classes</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <table>

            <tr>

                <td class='col1'>11</td>
                <td class='col2'>12</td>

            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td class='col1'>21</td>
                <td class='col2'>22</td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </body>

</html>
​
```

CSS

```
.highlight {

    /* your style here*/
    background: #00aa00; /* demo highlight*/

}
td {

    padding: 2px;

}
​
```

jQuery

```
$("table tr td").on("click", function(){

    var clss = $(this).attr('class');
    var selector = "table tr td." + clss;
    if (clss.match(/highlight/)) {
        $(".highlight").removeClass("highlight");
    } else if ($(".highlight").size() == 0) {
        $(selector).addClass("highlight");
    } 
});​
```

**EDIT**: here is the working jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qUcPK/2/